# ArrayList remove method

Tags: arraylist

I have a look at the ArrayList Source code，found remove method as follows：

```
  /**
 * Removes the element at the specified position in this list.
 * Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their
 * indices).
 *
 * @param index the index of the element to be removed
 * @return the element that was removed from the list
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
 */
public E remove(int index) {
    if (index >= size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));

    modCount++;
    E oldValue = (E) elementData[index];

    int numMoved = size - index - 1;
    if (numMoved > 0)
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                         numMoved);
    elementData[--size] = null; // clear to let GC do its work

    return oldValue;
}
```

why it doesn't consider the situation when index<0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing in a negative index would fail on the following line:

```
E oldValue = (E) elementData[index];
```

Specifically, an access to the `elementData` underlying array would happen with some negative index.  This would cause an [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) to be thrown, as the documentation describes:

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.

Hence, the `ArrayList#remove()` implementation does not need to do anything extra as the language will already handle the case of negative indices.

However, you might be wondering why the code *does* make the following check if the index is *larger* than the size:

```
 if (index >= size)
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
```

The reason this check is made is because it is possible that an index is passed in which is *within* the bounds of `elementData` but is *larger* than the logical size of the actual list/array.  In other words, the size of the underlying array does not (and often will not) need to be in lock step with the actual number of entries in the list.  Rather, the JVM will grow or shrink the `elementData` array as needed depending the size and usage of the list.

Comment: cannot upvote.vote cast by those with less than 15 reputation are record,but do not change the publicly display post score